# Is there a work around to for a multi select in a tree view?

Tags: xaml, treeview, multi-select

Is there a work around to for a multi select in a tree view?  This ability is not available in the xaml that I have seen.  If you could be very descriptive in how you handled the situation on your end that would be great I am a new developer.

Here is my xaml code
`

```
                    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

                    <TreeView.Resources>

                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightSkyBlue"/>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightSkyBlue"/>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />

                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type comModels:OptSetGroup}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Margin="3,3,0,3"
                                          Command="{Binding OptSetGroupClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Page}}"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding}">

                                </CheckBox>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="3,3,25,3" FontWeight="Bold"/>

                            </StackPanel>

                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type comModels:OptSet}">

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ToolTip="{StaticResource OptSetToolTip}">

                                <CheckBox Margin="3" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>


                                <!--<CheckBox FontWeight="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource TrueToBold}}" Margin="3"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>-->

                                <!--<CheckBox.Content>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" Foreground="Blue" Margin="3,0"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </CheckBox.Content>-->



                                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Code}" Margin="3,0" Foreground="Blue"
                                       FontWeight="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource TrueToBold}}" />

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="0,3,15,3"
                                       FontWeight="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource TrueToBold}}" />-->

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Code}" Margin="3" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="Blue"/>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="3,3,15,3"/>


                            </StackPanel>

                        </DataTemplate>

                    </TreeView.Resources>

                    <TreeView.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>

                            <MenuItem Header="Add"
                                  Command="{Binding AddOptSetCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>

                            <MenuItem Header="Edit"
                                  Command="{Binding EditOptSetCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete"
                                  Command="{Binding DeleteOptSetCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>

                            <MenuItem Header="Copy"
                                  Command="{Binding CopyOptSetCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>

                            <MenuItem Header="Import"
                                      Command="{Binding ImportOptSetCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>

                            <MenuItem Header="Wizard"
                                  Command="{Binding AddOptSetWizardCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>

                            <Separator/>

                            <!--<Grid Height="20">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Separator Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4, 0" Text="Batch Tools" Foreground="Black"/>
                        <Separator Width="20" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>


                    <MenuItem Header="Edit + Add Option"
                                  Command="{Binding BatchEditAddOptionCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>

                    <MenuItem Header="Edit + Remove Option"
                                  Command="{Binding BatchEditRemoveOptionCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>

                    <MenuItem Header="Edit + Find/Replace Option"
                                  Command="{Binding BatchEditFindReplaceOptionCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>

                    <MenuItem Header="Copy + Add Option"
                                  Command="{Binding BatchCopyAddOptionCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>

                    <MenuItem Header="Copy + Remove Option"
                                  Command="{Binding BatchCopyRemoveOptionCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>

                    <MenuItem Header="Copy + Find/Replace Option"
                                  Command="{Binding BatchCopyFindReplaceOptionCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>

                    <MenuItem Header="Option Set Wizard"
                                  Command="{Binding AddOptSetWizardCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>

                    <Separator/>-->

                            <MenuItem Header="Check All" Command="{Binding CheckAllCommand}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Uncheck All" Command="{Binding UncheckAllCommand}"/>

                            <Separator/>

                            <MenuItem Header="Delete Checked" Command="{Binding DeleteOptSetsCommand}"/>

                            <Separator/>

                            <MenuItem Header="Expand All" Command="{Binding ExpandAllCommand}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Collapse All" Command="{Binding CollapseAllCommand}"/>



                        </ContextMenu>
                    </TreeView.ContextMenu>

                </TreeView>
```

`
As you can see I have a check all and un check all which I am hoping can be similar.

I obviously tried to see If I was able to handle this through the XAML code and that is not possible.  I have taken a look at this solution https://github.com/codecadwallader/codemaid/blob/dev/CodeMaid/UI/TreeViewMultipleSelectionBehavior.cs and was not able to mimic this behavior.